# how to fix " Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, react-android

I'm new in react native, when i wanted to  run my first project, i got this error,

how to fix it, thanks for your attentions

> " Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1.

Searched in the following locations:

[this](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.1/gradle-3.4.1.pom)   and [this](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.1/gr)

project/buil.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2'
        }
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        //apply plugin: 'jetty'
        apply plugin: 'maven'
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-core:1.0.0-beta04'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta04'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

//task clean(type: Delete) {
 //   delete rootProject.buildDir
//}
```

Comment: what is the gradle version in build.gradle  ? can u post the `app/build.gradle` and `project/build.gradle` here.

Comment: @NabeelK thanks so much, i downloaded gradle3.4.1 but did not find the 2 file mentioned in the error message(.jar & .pom), i searached maven and dl.google, but did not find also, how can i find the files?